# Windows Phone 8.1 Bing-like slide page animation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'd like to add a page transition in my Windows Phone 8.1 app in such a way, that the following page will slide-in from the bottom of the screen. Similar effect is used when you launch Bing by hitting the *Search* button.

Unfortunately, the MSDN isn't much descriptive on that topic. Does anyone know how to implement such an animation?

Answer (score 17):

First you will have to disable current Transitions for the `Frame` - the best place would be in `App.xaml.cs` where the `rootframe` is created but it depends on how your App is initialized. Here for example is in MainPage constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Frame mainFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    mainFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
}
```

After you have disabled default Transitions, in every `Page` you can define its own Transition:

In `Page.xaml`:

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
       <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Bottom"/>          
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

I'm not sure if that is the exact animation you were looking for. More about animations you will find [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx).

Of course you can also define `Frame`'s new `ContentTransitions`, so that they would be as default for all `Pages` - for example:

```
// instead of null put in MainPage constructor:
mainFrame.ContentTransitions = new TransitionCollection { new PaneThemeTransition { Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Bottom } };
```

Comment: The solution you provided is almost perfect, thanks. That's exactly the type of animation I was thinking of. However, immediately after the animation starts, the former page goes black. The resulting effect is that the following page slides onto a black field instead of the former page. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @user3596795 Have you tried to set Theme animation for all Pages (at the end of the answer) - in that case the former Page will slide down before the new slides in.

Comment: After setting Theme animation for all Pages, the former Page indeed behaves as you described. But it's not exactly what I meant. I'd like the former Page to remain stationary when the following Page slides in. Do you have any clue how to achieve it?

Comment: @user3596795 It may be a hard Task - I think ThemeTransition contains both - in/out of UIElement, thus it may be hard to apply only *half* of it. Maybe you will have to try to write your own `Transition`, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user3596795 Were you able to find a way to keep the navigated-from page stationary while the navigated-to page transitions in?

Comment: @danhbear No, I haven't played with that much, yet.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to keep the previous page stationary?

Comment: Anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 3):

The default transitions can be overridden on per navigation basis from code.

```
NavigationTransitionInfo transitionInfo = new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo();
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), false, transitionInfo);
```

The code above will force the `SecondPage` to slide in from bottom exatly the way you want. However, this applies only to this particular navigation scenario. If you want `SecondPage` to slide in when navigated from anywhere, set the `NavigationTransitionInfo` in XAML.

```
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <SlideNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

This will force page to slide in whenever it's navigated to. This default can still be overridden via code for particular navigation scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

In [The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) you can find animations and samples

Here is some [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345129/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions)

Comment: I thinks he is using WP8.1 WinRT not WP7 Silverlight