# Have no page transition in Windows Phone runtime

Tags: navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, transition

I'm trying to disable Windows Phone runtime's default page navigation animation. All I could achieve, is to change it to either continuum, turnstile or slide, but I'd like the page to change instantaneously.
So when I call this.Frame.navigate() it should navigate to the new page without any animation.

In Silverlight, this was the default case, no page transitions out of the box. Now I can't get rid of them.

The reason why I am trying to accomplish this, is because I'd like to add my own animation, using storyboards for this one particular page transition.

Comment: Is this something similar what you're expecting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159946/windows-phone-8-1-bing-like-slide-page-animation

Comment: in App.xaml.cs you have to remove the code which adds an animation to TransitionCollection

Comment: And remove all transitions from the XAML of each page

Comment: Adding this:
mainFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
workedfor me. Thanks a lot!