# Disable launch transition in WP 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I wonder if it's possible delete the transition that leads to my WP8.1 universal app when it's launched. So, when my app is launched, I want it to just show the SplashScreen without any animation. I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24159946/windows-phone-8-1-bing-like-slide-page-animation/24160696#24160696) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388313/have-no-page-transition-in-windows-phone-runtime/) questions, but since I'm not navigating between pages within my app, I can't just set "ContentTransitions" of my frame to null.
Does anybody have any information on this? Or is it just not possible, since these "launching" transitions are managed by the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the animations on the Frame, hook up the Frame`s navigated event and enable them back after first navigation. I have a post about this [here](http://blog.kulman.sk/creating-a-fake-splashscreen-for-your-universal-app/).

Comment: If I got your blogpost right, then you are disabling the transition between the original splash screen and the "fake" splash screen. What I want to do is a little bit different: I want to disable the transition animation from the start menu (i.e. the list with all apps) to the splash screen... Does this really work in the same way?

Comment: So, maybe this is more precise: when my application is started, I wantno any animation at all. You tap the button, the SplashScreen is shown and then the content. No transition effects in between to smoothen anything!

Answer (score 0):

The initial splash screen is displayed by the OS until you call `Window.Current.Activate()`. You cannot disable/modify this transition, and you should also not try to do so as your app will lose parity with the rest of OS ecosystem.