# How to disable page animation while loading in WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How can I disable the page load animation (kind of turn-style) when a new page is loaded in windows phone 8.1 app? I tired searching on the net, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24160696/2681948) will help.

Comment: Go app.xaml.cs and delete ContentTransitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer

```
public MyPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Frame myFrame =(Frame)Window.Current.Content;
    myFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
}
```