# Remove Page Transition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I want to remove Page transitions completely from the page. I tried to search for this, but all I got was about Windows Phone 8 which doesn't work in WP8.1 environment.

I know with the help of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx) that I can add Transitions in the UI components and tried to put it for Page too, but it doesn't work at all. I get to see default page transition animation and the custom animation both.

So is there a way to remove or change page transition animation in Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24160696/2681948) - set *ContentTransitions* of your frame to `null`.

Comment: @Romasz Thanks for the hint. Yes that was the answer. I can either make it null or remove all elements from it. I was trying to remove it from Page, instead I should be looking at the Frame.

Comment: That will work for every page, but I'm not sure if you will be able to get rid of default transition for splash screen and when your app is resumen - not launched.

Comment: That is not required for my app anyways. So the code works for me. I am having some strange flickering in some pages though and have to set it null in every page for it to work.