# How to change page transition in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, fade, transition, flip

I'm doing an application in windows phone 8.1 that contains several pages and you can navigate between them.

Default animation when I change the page it's like a flip animation. Is it possible to change it?

I want a fade out (page that is going out) and fade in (page that is going in) in most of changes. Is it possible?

I tried to put this:

```
<Grid.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <ContentThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
</Grid.Transitions>
```

but I still see flip transition.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24159946/2681948) - maybe will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a `Navigation Transition` in each page to decide the transition used when you navigate to that screen.

For example, with this code you'll use a `SlideTransition` when you go to that screen and when you leave it:

```
<Page
    ...>
    <Page.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <NavigationThemeTransition>
                <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                    <SlideNavigationTransitionInfo />
                </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
            </NavigationThemeTransition>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Page.Transitions>
...
</Page>
```

Some transitions are:

- [CommonNavigationTransitionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.commonnavigationtransitioninfo)
- [SlideNavigationTransitionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.SlideNavigationTransitionInfo)
- ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo

I'm not sure if there're more or if you can choose a fade in/out.